# Add Text in ImageView on Android

Tags: java, android, imageview

I'm  currently having a viewlist composed of Imageview. I'm trying to add text on each imageview of the list.

Here is the view management: A call called the ImgView method with it's context and Associated view.

```
public ImgView(Context c, ImageView ImageV) {
    mImageView = filteredImage;
    mImageView.setTag(this);

    mFiltersText = new TextView(c);
    mFiltersText.setText("No effect");
    mFiltersText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    mContext = c;
    mImage = new GPUImage(mContext); 
    mEffect = R.id.none;
    mActivity = (Activity) mContext;
}
```

the mEffect is just an int used to know the type of effect I want to apply on the pic and stored in xml

```
<resources>
    <item type="id" name="none" />
    <item type="id" name="blackandwhite" />
    <item type="id" name="bla" />
</resources>
```

My goal is to find a way to get a string from the xml and display this string on the image view.

for example, when selecting "None" id, I display "No effect" on the image

I defined mFilterText but it's not displaying anything.

The View is get as shown below:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ....
    convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.list_item_filter, null);
    filteredImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.filteredImage);
    filteredImage.setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(mFakeBitmap));
    filteredText = new TextView(mContext);
```

it's possible that filteredText is not correctly used. I use it as new but perhaps I need to attached it ad the FilteredImage do.

Any idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just place TextView on top of ImageView.

Comment: How to put on top ? My Layout describe a Listview and I put inside the imageview

Comment: Inflate view of item from xml, for example `LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(layoutId, viewgroup, false);` Where layoutId is id of your layout with ViewGroup which contains ImageView with TextView.

Comment: Where do I need to add the info ? my ViewGroup is getting params from the ListView description in the xml file of the layout

Comment: Override getView or onCreateViewHolder in your adapter, depends of what kind of adapter you're using.

Comment: Add this TextView to your list_item_filter layout.

Comment: How to do it ? The code containing the convertview, filteredImage/Filtertext is coming from the getView

Answer (score 0):

Use a Framelayout

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

</FrameLayout>
```

You can also use the drawable property of textview

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_clear_white_24dp"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_clear_white_24dp"
    android:drawableBottom="@drawable/ic_clear_white_24dp"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_clear_white_24dp"
/>
```

Comment: My Layout is defined as FrameLayout but the ImageView is not define as an ImageView, The xml defined a ListView. Following this method the text appears but at the screen. My ListView contain a scrollable list of image. the imageview as argument of the method and get using Layoutinflater by the caller.